# In steady state diffusion of atoms, does dJ/dt = 0 hold true?

Tags: diffusion

My textbook says that under steady state flow the flux is independent of time and remains the same at any cross-sectional plane along the diffusion direction. Further, it gives the following conditions:

$$\left(\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}\right)_x = -\left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}\right)_t = 0$$

According to the book shouldn't $\dfrac{\text{d}J}{\text{d}t} = 0$ hold true also, as it says that the flux is independent of time? I've looked all over the internet, but I couldn't find $\dfrac{\text{d}J}{\text{d}t} = 0$ as a condition for steady state  flow.

Comment: Chem+Math MathJax formatting reference:
 [Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/) / [Upright vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)

Answer (score 1):

The **steady state** corresponds to the behaviour of the solutions of the equations of conservation of a physical-chemical system when $t \to \infty$. In practice, depending on the 'inertia' of the particular system, this state will be acquired very fast (seconds) or very slowly.

For chemical species $\ce{A}$ which does not react so its rate of reaction is zero (i.e. $r_\ce{A} = 0$), the statement of conservation of mass is
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial C_\ce{A}}{\partial t} +
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}_\ce{A} = r_\ce{A}
  \rightarrow
  \frac{\partial C_\ce{A}}{\partial t} +
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}_\ce{A} = 0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Eq. (1) is a PDE that states the concentration of species $\ce{A}$ as  function of space and time, i.e. $C_\ce{A} = C_\ce{A}(\mathbf{r},t)$. Consequently, the flux of $\ce{A}$ will also be a function of space and time, i.e. $\mathbf{J}_\ce{A} = \mathbf{J}_\ce{A}(\mathbf{r},t)$. However, in steady state the partial derivative with respect to time *is* zero, and thus Eq. (1) becomes
\begin{equation}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}_\ce{A} = 0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Eq. (2) is also a PDE but in here the flux is a function *only* of space, i.e. $\mathbf{J}_\ce{A} = \mathbf{J}_\ce{A}(\mathbf{r})$. Therefore, steady-state implies not only that the flux is independent of time, but that its divergence is zero.

The condition you are trying to find is not explained in books, but perhaps because it is fairly obvious. The independence of variables with time comes when crossing out the terms that depend on time of a specific PDE.

To make an analogy to Chemistry, if I give you Schrödinger's equation in paper without the term $i\hbar \partial \Psi / \partial t$, you won't be worried about time because you don't see the variable $t$ in another part of the PDE. Thus, it just comes naturally that $\Psi = \Psi(\mathbf{r})$ (or called $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ more typically). Similarly, if I give you the statement of the conservation of mass and you don't see the variable $t$, then it is obvious that the flux won't depend on time.